# Dual boot with Windows 7 & Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios

I have a HP Elite book 840G3 laptop with Windows installed in the primary drive and Ubuntu installed in the second drive. What is to be done to get to pick the operating system option on starting up.

Right now I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on startup and pick the needed drive from the BIOS
Boot Menu screen.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have successfully installed both OS’s and want to get the boot menu automatically without pressing any keys, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode (basically creating an EFI parition during installation.)/

**Legacy vs UEFI**

**Legacy (x86 bit)** - if you install Ubuntu with

- Root
- Swap

then the Ubuntu OS will be installed in Legacy Mode (meaning it won't support UEFI like Windows (x64bit).

**UEFI** - If you install Ubuntu with following paritions

- Root
- Swap
- EFI

on your PC/Laptop then the Os is installed in UEFI Mode. Usually devices that came into market post 2010 are UEFI Supported meaning x64bit.

Once you've installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode then during boot you will see Grub which also lists Windows bootloader.

Please visit - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI to learn and install Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: In which mode Ubuntu is installed depends on the mode you use to boot the installer. If you boot installer in UEFI-mode Ubuntu will be installed in UEFI-mode, if you boot installer in legacy-mode, Ubuntu will be installed in legacy-mode. Important is, that Windows and Ubuntu are installed in the same mode, either legacy-mode or UEFI-mode, otherwise Grub can't handle dual-boot.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Windows 7 Ultimate - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (x64) in dual-boot. While installing Ubuntu, the installer recommended Legacy mode instead of UEFI, because of something with Win7. At the first reboot, the Windows 7 option was missing from the GRUB Menu. All I had to do was running "sudo update-grub" command from a terminal in Ubuntu. At the next reboot, the Windows 7 option appeared in the GRUB Menu, and I was able to boot Win7 without any problem. That's why I love Ubuntu! Hope this helps others!